# How to forecast demand with time series and/or other models?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, zero-inflation, crostons-method

I need to forecast data which has many periods of zero demand, also there is no seasonality or trend in the data.

I tried ARIMA, but it converges to the mean. I also applied some predictors, but they don't affect the forecast significantly. What forecasting methods should I use?

Below is my dataset

**Time series:**

sales <-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

**Predictors:**

sales$dayOfWeek <- c(5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2)

sales$promo <- c(10,20,15,10,15,10,20,10,20,15,10,15,10,20,10,20,15,10,15,10,20,10,20,15,10,15,10,20,10,20,15,10,15,10,20,10,20,15,10,15,10,20,10,20,15,10,15,10,20,10,20,15,10,15,10,20,10,20,15,10,15)

sales$marketing <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0)

Comment: I looked at using your predictor series BUT they were of little value .. I would use a robust version of CROSTON

Comment: @IrishStat - is there any literature or links to articles/publications where I can read and understand more about the 'robust version of Croston' you are suggesting?

Comment: The precise procedure is proprietary to AFS but I can comment that it treats the data in a similar way to standard CROSTON but adjusts for Pulses and Level Shifts thus simultaneously discounting pulse anomalies and incorporating mean shifts. http://autobox.com/cms/images/dllupdate/AutoboxUsersguide.pdf 
 Chapter 7 contains an overview

Answer (score 5):

You can use **Croston's method** method for forecasting. Croston's method was developed for cases like yours. Forecasting demand when many variables are zeros. It is implemented with the `crost()` command from the forecast package in R.

It is well explained in the following questions:

[Analysis of time series with many zero values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8779/analysis-of-time-series-with-many-zero-values)

[Explain the croston method of R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127337/explain-the-croston-method-of-r)

The latter question was brilliantly answered by [Stephan Kolassa](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1352/stephan-kolassa). Here is the most basic part of [his answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/127366/1352).

> Note that Croston's method does not forecast "likely" periods with nonzero demands. It assumes that all periods are equally likely to exhibit demand. It separately smoothes the inter-demand interval and nonzero demands via Exponential Smoothing, but updates both only when there is nonzero demand. The in-sample fit and the point forecast then essentially is the ratio of smoothed nonzero demand, divided by the inter-demand interval (unless there is some kind of Syntetos-Boylan bias correction going on).

You can find the original paper from [Croston](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3007885?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

I also recommend you reading the following paper by [Shenstone and Hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/croston.pdf) and you can have a look at all the question with the [crostons-method](/questions/tagged/crostons-method) tag.

Comment: Thank you for your upvote if it was yours. I do not know if I tagged you correctly due to the spaces between firstname and family name. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: It indeed was me, and I'll take the liberty of editing a bit.

Comment: I highly appreciate the response @Ferdi and @Stephen! How can I apply **external predictors** (promotions, marketing etc.) in Croston's method?

Comment: in the case of where you have external predictors you can often build what is called a Transfer Function or Dynamic Regression . These models allow not only contemporaneous response but lead and lag effects of the predictors. Why don't you post one of your data sets..

Comment: @IrishStat thanks for the revert. I have added a dataset in the original question.

Comment: After a review of your data , It appears to me that you would be better served by a robust Croston method .

Comment: Is there any chance croston method available in python @Ferdi

Answer (score 4):

One of the problems with Croston's method is that if there is a level shift in the demand rate or if there are unusual demand rates the suggested approach is often insufficient. A robust Croston-like procedure is available in AUTOBOX which I have helped to develop. The idea is to identify and to adjust for these kinds of violations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an additional concept which can be implemented along with CROSTON, **Rolling Forecast**.

Can be used with any forecasting method. what it does is, at the time of forecasting it considers the most recent values and gives more weight-age, most likely to forecast better.

It is very helpful when implemented alongside Croston as 
for example: demand : 2,0,3,4,0,0,0,5,6

Now when you implement Croston with Rolling Window: 4, it considers something like this:

Croston gives more weight-age to 0,0,5,6 before predicting and these most recent 0's are given more importance than that of 0 which was in the start.

Hope this would be helpful for you!

For better understanding,
can refer to https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/rolling-forecasts/, explained with an example.